# Error: List index out of range(Python)

Tags: python

My program reads a file .txt and gets an information from each line of this file.

Lets say i have a line "*0: 15.5 0 3 5 6*".

My program will get the 15.5 and save in the y_value list.

```
def readFile(filepath):
mFile = open(filepath)
y_values = []
lines = [x for x in mFile.readlines() if x[0]!='#' and x[0]!='\n'and x!='']
print filepath
for line in lines:
    line = line.replace("\t", " ").replace("\n",' ').replace(':','')
    tokens = [x for x in line.split(" ") if x!='']

    y_values.append(tokens[1])
return y_values
```

It says the `y_values.append(tokens[1])`is where is happening.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: You most probably have a line with only 1 number or only whitespaces. Did you check your file if that is the case?

Comment: You should paste the traceback (and fix your indentation). That said, it looks like `tokens` has less than two elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that all your lines with data have at least two tokens, then the most likely explanation is that you have a blank line (or a line with only blanks and a linefeed).  Anyway, files are their own iterators these days, and you could use generator expressions rather than lists to strip comments and blank lines, so instead of this:

lines = [x for x in mFile.readlines() if x[0]!='#' and x[0]!='\n'and x!='']

You could use the following statements to strip lines that start with '#' and insure that there are no remaining blank lines.

```
lines = (x.rstrip() for x in mFile if not x.startswith('#'))
lines = (x for x in lines if x)
```

Also, you could use a with statement to properly close the file.  Start your function with:

```
with open(filepath) as mFile:
```

and indent the rest of the function (until the return) below it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def readFile(filepath):
mFile = open(filepath)
y_values = []
lines = [x for x in mFile.readlines() if x[0]!='#' and x[0]!='\n'and x!='']
print filepath
for line in lines:
    try:
        line = line.replace("\t", " ").replace("\n",' ').replace(':','').rstrip()
        tokens = [x for x in line.split(" ") if x!='']

        y_values.append(tokens[1])
    except IndexError:
        print line
return y_values
```

I have added the `rstrip()` to remove in tail garbage. Also I would add a try catch block to find out which line exactly causing this issue. That way you can get an idea of a solution.